# How to use the 'solidity' property of the regionprops function of MATLAB in Octave?

Tags: matlab, function, image-processing, octave

I have a code in MATLAB that I have to convert into Octave. I have problems with the following command:

```
boxes = regionprops (L, 'Solidity')
```

where `L` is a binary image class double.

Octave does not know the `'Solidity'` property . Is there a similar property or a function that I can use to run the code in Octave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the definition of 'Solidity' in matlab [`regionprops`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) this measurement is the Area/ConvexArea.

In order to calculate the `ConvexArea` do the following things:

1. Get id list of the connected component pixels. Use: `regioprops(I,'PixelIdxList')`
2. Calculate their `convexhull`. Use: `H = convhull (x, y)`
3. Calculate the area of the `convexhull`. Use: `polyarea(convexHullX,convexHullY)`

Comment: Thank you, but Octave does not know the 'ConvexArea' either. Is there a similar property or function for that one?

Comment: Does Octave have 'ConvexHull' or 'ConvexImage'?

Comment: I think it doesn't. http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/function/regionprops.html                       There are different functions called 'convhull' und 'convhulln', but I have had problems using them because my input is an image.  https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.3/Convex-Hull.html#Convex-Hull

Comment: I tried to use 'regionprops(I, 'PixelIdxList')' and got a 1 x 364 struct array, where 364 is the number of objects that were found in I, right? My problem now is that the array is full of high numbers that I dont understand... I thought that the array should be made of vectors containing the indices of the component pixels but it is just those numbers that I see... So how can I find x and y for the next function (convhull)? Maybe I just got it wrong but I really dont understand..

Comment: According to this, http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/function/regionprops.html, you suppose to get the indices of the all the pixels

Comment: Also if this is a struct array each value is supposed to be a struct. What is inside the struct?

Comment: I think I got it now, thank you! Those numbers were the linear indices and I had to add the command 'ind2sub' to get x and y out of them. Unfortunately, the result is still different from the wanted one (when working on Matlab with the 'Solidity'-Property). But I might have made a mistake somewhere..