# Is there an alternate way to calculate Solidity in regionprops.Solidity in the image package in Octave?

Tags: image-processing, octave, feature-extraction

I have been trying to use the regionprops function in Octave for Feature extraction from a k-means segmentation of an ultrasound image. The regionprops function has several properties among which is Solidity, which is Area/ConvexArea. I'm on Octave 4.4.1 with the latest image package installed and loaded. However, when I try to use those properties, I get the error **property "Solidity" not yet implemented**. It shows the same error if I try to compute ConvexArea as well. Is there an alternate way to calculate it ? I saw a thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39309710) that shows a method. However, I tried that and couldn't calculate the convex area using the method shown there

Code for reference:

```
    properties = regionprops(label, 'Area', 'Solidity');
    density = [properties.Solidity]; #throws error here (not yet implemented error)
    convex_area = [properties.ConvexArea]; #same error here as well 
    area = [properties.Area];

    density = area/convex_area;
    densecond = density > 0.5;

    denseMax = max(area(densecondd));
    I_bin2 = bwareafilt(Seg_BI, [5 1000]);
    [m n] = size(I_bin2);
    norm = abs(0.1*n);
    normr = abs(0.1*m);
    I_bin2(:,1:norm) = 0;
    I_bin2(:,n-norm:n) = 0;
    I_bin2(1:normr,:) = 0;
    I_bin2(m-normr:m,:) = 0;
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the error. `'Solidity`' on Octave 4.4.1 using a labeled image is working fine for me. What version of the image package are you using? I'm on 2.12.0.

Comment: The property `Solidity` was added to the image package in version 2.10.0. Are you sure you are using the latest version of the image package?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble .. The latest version of the image package was not loaded yet, thus the issue. I was able to get it working after a fresh install and load. Thanks a lot for the replies !